# Mutliple http routes on Elastic Beanstalk load balancer for node app with multiple servers

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, websocket

Having difficulty phrasing my question, so I could not find much info on it so I will explain:

I have a node.js app that hosts a restify/express api on port 8081.
This same api hosts a websocket server on port 8083.

All this works wonderfully on localhost by specifying the ports, but in a hosted environment it needs to run on port 80 http. (omitting 443 for simplicity).

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk (nginx server). When I deployed my app, it creates an EC2 and ELB (load balancer) instance. The ELB then has a public dns which I use to access the api on port 80. There is no special listeners configured (only 80 and 443). So I am not sure how it gets to the api on port 8081. The EC2 instance also only allows 80 and 443.

The api works fine using it with the ELB public dns on port 80.

Now I have added the websocket server in there.

My problem is - I need another public dns on port 80 to go to the socket server on port 8083 of the same Beanstalk app. How would I approach this?

I would appreciate any thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that..

1. Elastic Beanstalk creates a Classic load balancer which does not support websockets.
2. Default nginx setup on AWS does not allow `Upgrade` headers.

However, I got it working in the following manner:

- Default EB setup (with classic ELB) serves the API as it normally did.
- Then I created an ALB (Application load balancer) from the EC2 dashboard.
- I added a target that routes to my EC2 instance (that EB created) on port 8083 (my websocket listener). My API runs on port 8081. Then add the target to the new ALB on on the Listeners tab.

This will allow traffic that hits the new ALB on port 80 to route to port 8083 of the server where my application is hosted.

- In my `.ebextensions` file in the project, I added the following that will update nginx settings to allow the `Upgrade` header that is needed for websockets:

Add to `.ebextensions`

```
container_commands:
  enable_websockets:
    command: |
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
              ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

So basically I have two load balancers. The default one that routes 80 to 8081, and another (ALB) that routes 80 to 8083.

This is by no means perfect. Auto scaling/load balancing would probably not work. But for now is serves the API and websocket server from the same application.

Comment: Just to add - This is actually what ALB was meant to do. I need to read up and see how to configure it properly.

Comment: This web socket issue is pretty much AWS's poor (or complicated) documentation. You set me on the right track. **The key aspect is that beanstalk instances created from the console do not support Application ELB**. You need to create it from EB CLI, when asked: 
Select a load balancer type
1) classic
2) application
Choose Application. [AWS Docs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/08/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-application-load-balancer/)

Comment: I see now they have an option to upgrade. If you go to EC2 > Load Balancers and select the classic load balancer that EB created - look for the "Migration" tab. It says:
`Migrate this Classic Load Balancer to a next generation load balancer. See Comparison of Elastic Load Balancing Products`

It seems like that will upgrade it to a proper ALB.